# Can't copy data into NTFS-formatted external HDD from Macbook

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, ntfs, macbook, file-transfer

I have copied my whole HDD into a Macbook Pro. Now I formatted the HDD from FAT32 to NTFS. Macbook is not allowing me to copy the data back to the HDD. What do I do now?

Comment: Related: [Solutions for writing to NTFS drives in OS X](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/solutions-for-writing-to-ntfs-drives-in-os-x/).

Answer (score -1):

This is normal that mac wont allow you to connect the ntfs file system drive in write mode. By default it will attach it in read only mode and this is the reason that restricts you from copying you in to ntfs file system drive.

If possible reformat it to fat32 and try copying the data or Google around to crack the restriction to allow Ntfs write. Where you need to be some caution during the process and it is not recommend.

Comment: Well your answer provides no possible solution.